Device Tree in Buildroot for ADAU1761 Codec and Beaglebone Black
I have a Beaglebone Black rev C, and an ADAU1761 evaluation board https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/evaluation-documentation/eval-adau1761z.pdf
The I2C address of the codec is 0x38 (the configurable address pins on the eval board are wired to ground)
I am using buildroot for the build system. I want to add an device tree overlay in the buildroot menuconfig so that the Beaglebone will recognize the codec.  My overlay file looks like this:
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&i2c2>;  //should this be &i2c1?  I tried both
        __overlay__ {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            status = "okay";

            adau1761: codec@38 {
                compatible = "adi,adau1761";
                reg = <0x38>;
            };
        };
    };
};


From the control port on the eval board, pin 1 SCL and pin3 SDA  are connected to P9 pin 19 and pin 20 of the beaglebone respectively.
Where in the buildroot menuconfig can I put the path to my overlay?  In Kernel menu, I see "Out-of-tree Device Tree Source file paths".  In Bootloaders menu, and using U-Boot, I see "Additional configuration fragment files".  I've tried a build pointing to my dts file using each of these.  But when I issue the alsa command aplay -L, I see the following:
# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=Black
    TI BeagleBone Black, davinci-mcasp.0-i2s-hifi i2s-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Black
    TI BeagleBone Black, davinci-mcasp.0-i2s-hifi i2s-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device

So it seems my overlay was not successfully compiled and loaded properly.  I could try to compile the dts file and place the dtbo file somewhere?  But doesn't buildroot expect the source file?
The kernel I am using is linux-5.10.30-ti-r3.tar.gz .  The main change I made to the defconfig is:
CONFIG_SND_SOC_ADAU1761_I2C=y
The buildroot defconfig is:
BR2_arm=y
BR2_cortex_a8=y
BR2_ARM_FPU_VFPV3=y
BR2_GLOBAL_PATCH_DIR="board/beaglebone/patches"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_EXTERNAL=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_EXTERNAL_BOOTLIN=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_EXTERNAL_BOOTLIN_ARMV7_EABIHF_GLIBC_STABLE=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ISSUE="Welcome to ADAU1761 BBB"
BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_CREATION_DYNAMIC_MDEV=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ROOT_PASSWD="dttfs@!"
BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY="/home/andrew/buildroot/board/andrew-bbb/rootfs-overlay"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT="board/beaglebone/post-build.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT="support/scripts/genimage.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_SCRIPT_ARGS="-c board/beaglebone/genimage.cfg"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL_LOCATION="$(call github,beagleboard,linux,5.10.30-ti-r3)/linux-5.10.30-ti-r3.tar.gz"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE="/home/andrew/buildroot/board/andrew-bbb/linux/defconfig"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME="am335x-evm am335x-bone am335x-boneblack am335x-bonegreen am335x-evmsk am335x-boneblue am335x-boneblack-wireless"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH="/home/andrew/buildroot/board/andrew-bbb/adau1761/adau1761-beaglebone-black-i2c-i2s.dts"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTB_OVERLAY_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_NEEDS_HOST_OPENSSL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSACONF=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ACONNECT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSALOOP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSAUCM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSATPLG=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_AMIDI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_AMIXER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_APLAY=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_APLAYMIDI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ARECORDMIDI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ASEQDUMP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ASEQNET=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_BAT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_IECSET=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_SPEAKER_TEST=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_MEDIATEK_MT7601U=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_MEDIATEK_MT7610E=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_MEDIATEK_MT76X2E=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RALINK_RT61=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RALINK_RT73=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RALINK_RT2XX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RTL_81XX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RTL_87XX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RTL_88XX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LINUX_FIRMWARE_RTL_RTW88=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGTA=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBNL_TOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_CONNMAN=y
BR2_PACKAGE_CONNMAN_WIFI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_CONNMAN_CLIENT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_DROPBEAR=y
BR2_PACKAGE_IW=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WIRELESS_TOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WIRELESS_TOOLS_LIB=y
BR2_PACKAGE_NANO=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_BUILD_SYSTEM_KCONFIG=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_VERSION=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_VERSION_VALUE="2021.04"
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_BOARD_DEFCONFIG="am335x_evm"
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_NEEDS_DTC=y
# BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_FORMAT_BIN is not set
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_FORMAT_IMG=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_SPL=y
BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_SPL_NAME="MLO"
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_DOSFSTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENIMAGE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_MTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_RUSTC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_UBOOT_TOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_UBOOT_TOOLS_FIT_SUPPORT=y

I'd appreciate any advice on what to try.

You provide an adequate description of the hardware you're using, but very little about the software. That's backwards since your questions are actually about software procedures. You also completely avoid mentioning the name of the "kernel". What versions are you using? What defconfig files are you using? The "kernel" image, a dtb, and any dtbo files would be loaded into memory and handed off to the "kernel" by U-Boot. This procedure could use a single FIT file, or individual files. What method are you using?

Thanks for your feedback. I have edited the question to include a better description of the software configuration.
